# Setting up centralized authentication and profiles in a Windows network

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

1 Windows 2k3/2k8 Server (File Server, Accounting Server, etc) [I need Windows server because I to run some servers (accounting) that are windows only)
5 Windows Client (Can be XP or Windows 7)

I dont want to give the server the load of loading up an OS as well so I will setup the machines with fully working OSes. Now my main question is that I want to setup the clients in such a way that they get the auth part from the server so well I can have anyone login from anywhere, also such that the home dir is a roaming one so no matter what system a person is working on he gets the same settings every time. (All software will be installed on all system, but not everyone will have access to everything). So basically I need the main Users home dir roaming and to get user settings from the server as well. What would be the best way to go about this? 
(Just point me in the right direction, I know my fairly nicely around networks and Linux systems, new to Windows management)

Comment: I'm editing your post, because this has nothing to do with thin clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Active Directory for authentication and Roaming Profiles and/or Folder Redirection via GPO for user roaming.

Comment: **Thank you** very much. Exactly what I was looking for :)